# Typescript is giving me undefined when appending data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state:

```
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState()
```

Here is my setState:

```
   const fileselectedHandler = (event: any): void => {
    setFile((event.target.files[0]))
  }
```

I have a function which uploads a picture and whenever I'm trying to pass FormData a new data I'm getting this error:

`Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.  TS2345`

Here is my function itself:

```
    const uploadPicture = (e:any) : void => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('avatar',file)
    console.log('--------data', data);
    currentUser.map((user:any)=>{
      axios.post(`http://localhost:4001/upload/${user.id}`,data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
        .then((res) => {
          window.location.reload(false);
          console.log('--------res', res);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log('--------err', err);
        })
    })
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: Try `data.append('avatar', file as Blob)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you need to upload it by creating a Blob object. I had the similar issue and doing this worked for me.

```
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('avatar',new Blob([file], { type: file.type }), file.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, your `React.useState()` is missing an parameter. I'm not sure if this breaks anything, but you don't supply the function with a default value.